# SharePoint 2013 restore site collection from management shell error?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have 2 SharePoint servers

1. From server A I took site collection backup
2. Now server A is totally down and I installed new SharePoint 2013 in server B

Now I want to restore site collection from server A to server

I run below command

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity "http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test" -Path C:\Users\spvfarm\Desktop\t\hrc.bak -DatabaseServer af-dbt1-srv -DatabaseName WSS_Content_test2 -HostHeader http://af-sp-srv -Force -GradualDelete -Verbose
```

but it gives blow error:

> Restore-SPSite: The web application at http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test counld  not be found.
>       verify that you have typed the URL correctly. 
>       If the URL should be serving existing content,
>   the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application

Comment: Do you have a web application created on that site and a site collection in that path created?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need a web application created on farm B at http://af-spt1-srv
Second, lets clean up your command...it has a mix of parameters from remove-spsite and restore-spsite and some you just don't need.  Use this instead: Restore-SPSite -Identity "http://af-spt1-srv/sites/test" -Path C:\Users\spvfarm\Desktop\t\hrc.bak -DatabaseServer af-dbt1-srv -DatabaseName WSS_Content_test2

Reasoning is hostheader is for host header based site collections.  You have path based site collection listed, so this isn't needed.  -Force should NEVER be used as a default command.  You need to know and understand why you are using it.  Example, overwriting an existing site collection at the same location would be a reason to use it, but you are creating a new site collection from this, so it isn't needed.  -Gradualdelete is part of the remove-spsite command.  -Verbose you can keep if you need to see the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a web application in farm B. After creating the web application, get the URL and execute the command bellow:

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity "<webApplicationUrl>/sites/test" -Path "<backupFilePath>" -DatabaseServer "<DBServer>" -DatabaseName "<DBNameCreatedWithTheWebApplication>" -Force
```

If your farm is using only one DBServer you can remove the parameters DatabaseServer and DatabaseName.

Answer (score -2):

check the permission of the account and even run powershell as administrator.